# Got an error: Undefined offset: 1 in Laravel 8

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I just open my project and run it into the browser.
I found an error:

ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /home/john/Documents/api4/api4/resources/views/livewire/crud/index-component.blade.php)

before closing my code editor it's never happened, so what is the problem with that?

I do follow this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/undefined-offset-1-laravel-livewire

and it not solved because I don't have section in the file

this is my code in the blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .header {
        background-color: aquamarine;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    h5 {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .main {
        background-color: beige;
        height: 600px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }




    .footer {
        background-color: #bdf7f1;
        height: 80px;
    }


    .slideleft {
       
        width: 200px;
        top: 100;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 80;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #f5bdf7;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .slideleft tbody {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }

    .header h5 {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .center {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 50px;
    }

</style>
  @livewireStyles
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img width="100" src="https://png2.cleanpng.png"
            alt="">
      </div>
      <div>

        <h5>Addres Book</h5>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="main">


    <div class="slideleft">
        <div class="upper">
            <a href="{{ route('addstudents') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="text-align: center;">
                <button>Add New Contact</button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <tbody>
            @if ($students->count() > 0)
                @foreach 
                ($students as $student)
                    <tr>
                       
                        <a href="{{ route ('editstudents', ['id' => $student->id]) }}"  class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                            style="padding: 1px 8px;">
                            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
                        </a>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No students found!</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody>

    </div>


</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>

@livewireScripts
```

this in the component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Crud;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Student;
use App\Http\Livewire\Crud\EditStudentComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\Attribute\Required;

class IndexComponent extends Component
{

public $search, $delete, $image, $confirmdel, $user_id;
public $sure = null;

protected $queryString = [
    'search'
];


// protected $listeners = ['deleteconfirmed' => 'deleteaccount'];

protected $listeners = ['showedit'];



public function showedit($theshow)
{
    $this->emit('showedit', $this->id);
    // dd($this->id);
}



public function deleteaccount($id)
{

    $student = Student::where('id', $id)->first();
    $student->delete();
    session()->flash('message', 'Student has been deleted successfully');
}


public $studentconfirmed = null;

public function confirm($studentconfrim)
{
    $this->studentconfirmed = $studentconfrim;

    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showconfirm');
}

public function mount($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function render()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $students = Student::where('user_id', $user_id);

    $students->when($this->search, function ($query, $search) use ($user_id) {
        
        return  $query->where('name', 'like', "%$search%",)
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%")
                    ->Where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                    ->orWhere('birth', 'like', "%$search%")
                    ->Where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                    ->orWhere('phone', 'like', "%$search%")
                    ->Where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                    
            ;
    });

    return view('livewire.crud.index-component', [
        'students' => $students->paginate(5),
    ]);


    return view('livewire.crud.index-component', [
        'students' => Student::where('user_id', $user_id)->get()


        

    ]);

}

// public function editstudent()
// {

//     dd('cek');
//     return view('livewire.crud.index-component', [
//         'editstudents' => Student::find($this->id),
//     ]);
// }


  }
```

any advice for me guys?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're returning the view twice. Instead of `->get()` you could just have `->paginate(5)`. So try returning the view once with:

```
return view('livewire.crud.index-component', [
        'students' => Student::where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(5)
    ]);
```

Comment: yeah, I just change based on your advice, it's still got the same thing Sir